# How to center an element between another element and the edge of the container

Tags: html, css

I've tried centering the first button between the second and the right edge using `margin:0 auto;` then `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` but to no avail. Whats the best way to accomplish this?

```
<nav class="bg">    
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button id="center">Button 3</button>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gabewest1/1915gwmy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/1915gwmy/2/ check this updated code

```
.bg {
    background-color:black; 
  text-align:center;
}
#center {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:green;
}
button {
  float:left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
button:last-child {
  float:none;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to explain how the `float:none` behaviors is working in this context? i've never used it before.